# dynatable - Custom behavior lost after pagination

Tags: dynatable

https://jsfiddle.net/wxLwx2hn/3/

I have created a dynatable that contains an "a tag" which opens an alert when clicked. The code works when the table is first created. It fails to work after any dynatable events such as pagination, sorting or page changing.

Behavior is given to the dynatable with the following

```
$("table#myTable").dynatable().on("dynatable:afterProcess", WireUpBehaviour());

  function WireUpBehaviour() {
    $("a.doSomething").on("click", function() {
    alert("working");
  });

}
```

How do I force the dynatable to call WireUpBehaviour function again after it has carried out pagination, sorting or page changing?

Answer (score 0):

I decided in the end just to use jQuery DataTable. It's got a better API and more resources!